# UIButton does not show titleLabel

Tags: objective-c

The following code basically does work, only the titleLabel is not shown when the result is displayed.

`buttonRect`is just a `CGRect` containing the buttons frame. I don't think the cause of the problem is there, because the button is displayed at the position he should be at.

`[contactButton.titleLabel center]` did not help, bringing the subview titleLabel to front didn't either.

```
UIButton *contactButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
contactButton.frame = buttonRect;

contactButton.titleLabel.text = @"Contact Someone!";
[contactButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showContactWindow) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.tabBarController.view addSubview:contactButton];
```

I really have no idea what could be causing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[myButton setTitle:@"Contact Someone!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```